# How to find rang of 4G Network and detect poor connection speed?

Tags: android, performance, networking

I have implemented logic for finding 2g and 3g network poor quality rang but cant find for 4g and in my case I have 4g phone but not high speed of internet, has anyone tried this?

Comment: Have you detected 4G network?

Comment: yes I have detected

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength)?

Comment: nope will try Thanks

Comment: its not working

Comment: Why ? Any issue ? Have you checked [this](https://www.truiton.com/2014/08/android-onsignalstrengthschanged-lte-strength-measurement/)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197557/discussion-between-richa-shah-and-piyush).

Comment: Your issue has been solved?